# Parametric curve arc length! Am I doing it right?

Tags: calculus, parametric

$x=3t^2+2$ and $y=2t^3-1$ on $[1,3]$

The formula for parametric arc length is 
$\int\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$

$x'(t) = 6t,y'(t)=6t^2$

Under the radical, I get $36t^2+36t^4$, which will factor into $36t^2(t^2+1)$, and square rooting that.. I get
$$6\int_1^3{t\sqrt{t^2+1}}\;dt$$
Obviously this is a simple u-substitution integration, for which I get 
$2{u}^{3/2}$ and integrate from 1 to 3, changing the limits to 2 and 10 because it is a function of $u$... which gives me $$2({10}^{3/2}-{2}^{3/2})$$
Is this correct?

Comment: No, u = t^2+1, du = 2tdt, dt = du/2t, so it gives you 6/2, which is 3... 3/(3/2) gives you 2

Comment: My mistake, I missed the $dt$ coefficient. Well, you nailed this integral!